# What differences are their in the Tau rules between the Compendium and Chalnath?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I recently started getting into Kill Team with a couple of my children.  One of them is collecting Tau, and we’re taking the rules from the *Kill Team: Compendium* book.

In issue 478, July 2022 of *White Dwarf*, a new series has started involving five Kill Teams.  One of these is Tau, but the article says the rules for them will be coming from *Chalnath*, not from *Compendium*.

Are the *Chalnath* rules a simple rebalancing of those from *Compendium*, or are they a major makeover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pathfinder kill team from Chalnath has different operatives to the Hunter Cadre kill team from the compendium, although there is one combination of operatives that is the same between the two.

If you formed a Hunter Cadre kill team from two pathfinder fire teams, that would match a Pathfinder kill team. You would have 1 leader and 12 other operatives, two could be heavy gunners and up to half could be drones.

There are no rules for Fire Warriors or Stealth Suits in the Chalnath rules, including the Fire Warrior fire team specific drones.